# PHP: obtain the url page that call my page php

Tags: php, uri

I have an HTML page that calls my page php.

I want via php to obtain the URL that calls me.

I have tried `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` but it returns me the URL of my page.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Please note that this value is not 100% sure (it's possible for the client/users to modify it), but it's still what's closest from what you want.